# Is there a way to see if certain integers are in certain places within an arraylist?

Tags: java, netbeans, arraylist, int, indexof

For example, if an arraylist holds the values [1, 2, 3], is there any way to check if they are in that order using indexOf or any other way?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to check if a list is sorted?

Comment: No, I am wondering if you can check if an arraylist has certain values in certain places of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the order and the array with a for-loop:

```
public boolean isArrayInOrder(int[] array, int... order) {
    if(array.length == order.length) {
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            if(array[i] != order[i]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```